# Some satements in for loop not executing at each iteration

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int NC=0,k=0;
char mychar;
scanf("%d",&NC);
for(k=0;k < NC;k++)
{ 
printf("\nenter a character:-");
scanf("%c",&mychar);
printf("\n%c",mychar);

}
return 0;
}
```

statements below first printf statement are executing at alternative iteration of the for loop.
ie. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8EYL.jpg)

Comment: Please, don't put `\n` to the beginning of string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a character at the keyboard, you press one key for the character, and then you press **ENTER**. Two characters are in the input stream: the character you enter, and a newline character. `scanf()` is leaving a `\n` character behind in the input stream. This newline character gets picked up by `scanf()` in the next iteration of the loop. Change to:

```
scanf(" %c",&mychar);
```

to skip over leading whitespace characters, including newlines.

To expand on this a little more, `scanf()` reads characters from the input stream. The `%c` specifier matches one character, so the second character, a `\n`, is left in the input stream. By adding a leading space: `" %c"`, you are telling `scanf()` to first match zero or more whitespace characters (newline characters are whitespace characters, as are `\t` and `\r`), then to match another character, which is then stored in `mychar`. This way even when the next character to be read from the input stream is a newline character, it is skipped over. Note that most conversion specifiers automatically skip over leading whitespace characters. The ones that don't are: `%c`, `%[]`, and `%n`.

Comment: thanx man...it worked..but can u explain the problem a little bit more..

Comment: its perfect..thanx